# I can't make GitHub Page work, what am i missing?

Tags: angular, github, github-pages

im working since several days on my angular project and i want to publish it on github pages. I have follow every doc and every tutorial i have found =>

- i have my public repos
- i have my functional angular project
- i build with ng build --output-path docs --base-href /repository-name/
- i publish the code on my repos
- i use GitHub Page Settings to setup my page with the good branch and the "Doc" folder.
  [image]

And i have lot of differents errors :

- first, the page was displaying the READ.ME (??)
- then i got : Not allowed to load local resource
- and now i have this :
  [image]

It's supposed to be easy to use, what am i missing??

Comment: Would you characterize this as a question about programming or software development?